# Automatically calculate the weight of a mesh

Tags: rigging, rigify

After parenting all meshes with armature, one of them (hair) is not affected by bones.

The weight of all objects has been automatically calculated in `parent > armature deform > with automatic weights`.

In this capture you can see the weight of the vertex group in de body affected by the bone `DEF-spine.006`. It is right:

[image]

In this other capture you can see the weight of the hair mesh for the same bone. It is wrong. the hair mesh is not affected by the bone at all. Therefore, moving the bone moves the head but not the hair.

When I did the automatic calculation, the hair mesh was included in the selected objects, but it seems to be unaffected.

[image]

I could try hand-painting the weight of the hair, but I find it difficult (or impossible) to match the same weight of the head in its specific gradient.

Why hasn't the same weight been applied to the hair mesh as to the mesh body? How can I get hair to be included in the automatic weight calculation?

Sorry for not including the original file. It seems that the upload site (https://pasteall.org/) is down.

Comment: Parenting With Automatic Weights may fail, in your case what you can try (if you want to avoid the weight painting which should not be too difficult), you can separate the hair as another object, parent it to the armature, then join it back to the body

Comment: ok, thanks. Right now the hair is a separated mesh, so it can be done quickly.